# Computing Many Slow I/O Operations

Tags: curated-data

In working on a custom stock screener, I often need to run mathematica code like this:

```
{#, FinancialData[#, "DividendYield"]} & /@ Take[FinancialData["NYSE:*"], 30]
```

In this example, I've limited the result set to 30, but ideally I'd like to get the dividend yield for a much larger set.

This is a specific example of a more general problem I have with mathematica, which is that sometimes I need to run a large number of distinct network IO calls and this blocks further computations.

Is there some workaround for writing calls like this that won't block further computations? I am a fairly competent programmer and therefore can implement a system in my Mathematica code to compute results one at a time, but I am trying to avoid reinventing the wheel. I feel this must be a very common problem for Mathematica users who use the built in data sources/Wolfram|Alpha integration.

Comment: You can start two distinct kernels (or better: two instances of Mathematica front end too, if you're not on a Mac).  But then they won't share variables.  Alternatively you can evaluate in a subkernel.  The relevant functions are `ParallelSubmit` and ``Parallel`Developer`QueueRun``.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into the documentation for those calls and do some experimentation.

Comment: I'll post a full answer tomorrow if I have time, or hopefully someone else will do it before that.

Comment: @Szabolcs one can start multiple mma frontends on a mac too (by directly exectuing the relevant file inside the Mathematica.app bundle)

Comment: @acl I never used a Mac, I've just been told that it's not easy to do it, and I wanted to avoid another comment about that.  Two kernels should suffice anyway, I just prefer two front ends for these things in case I crash or (more likely) freeze one of them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As Szabolcs mentions, the simplest way to do this is to start a new kernel and push this bulk of data acquisition to that kernel and let it run in the background. There are good examples in the documentation in [`tutorial/ConcurrencyManagingParallelProcesses`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ParallelTools/tutorial/ConcurrencyManagingParallelProcesses.html).

For your specific case, here's an example following the above:

```
LaunchKernels[1];
j = ParallelSubmit[{#, FinancialData[#, "DividendYield"]} & /@ 
   Take[FinancialData["NYSE:*"], 30]];
```

[image]

```
Parallel`Developer`QueueRun[]
Out[3]= True
```

[image]

You can continue working as usual in your main kernel.

Answer (score 4):

### Parallel Kernels for separate Notebooks

Perhaps you simply want to run two kernels in parallel.  You can do this by:

1. Open **Evaluation > Kernel Configuration Options...** and set up more than one kernel.
2. Assign a different kernel to each of two Notebooks using **Evaluation > Notebook's Kernel**

From there you can run your slow code in one Notebook and do your interactive programming in the other.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

### "Dialogs" on a single Kernel

> I guess the main point of my question is, if I'm launching an external command, even if I am waiting for feedback from it, it shouldn't take up a kernel's resources ... also not to mention that I'm being a complete jerk launching two kernels when we only have 2 on our network seat.

Perhaps your best option in that case is to run calculations in a kernel dialog while the background task is momentarily paused.  On my system the shortcut key for **Evaluation > Evaluate in Subsession** is <kbd>F7</kbd>.

As an example try:

```
Do[Pause[1], {i, 50}];
```

And while it is running put the cursor in a separate cell containing:

```
Print[i]
```

And press <kbd>F7</kbd>.

Every time you select that cell and press <kbd>F7</kbd> you should get the current value of `i` from the evaluating `Do` loop.

[image: Mathematica graphics]