# Determining the partitioning of Do loop iterations between kernels?

Tags: parallelization

Say I have some `Do` loop that I'd like to evaluate in parallel: `Do[Something, {i, 1, M}]`.  I'd like to split this list up into chunks which individual kernels evaluate.  However, I would like to explicitly specify these chunks, which is something `ParallelDo` does not seem to allow for.

How does `ParallelDo` actually partition values of $i$ to be evaluated during a `Do` loop?

If I have a list $L$ where I need to access $L[i]$ at the $i$th iteration of the `Do` loop, how might I avoid slowdowns associated with using some large global list?

Comment: You can partition the jobs and use `ParallelSubmit` as here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2877/5 (possible duplicate)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can control the partitioning using the `Method` option of `Parallel*` functions.  This is documented under [`Parallelize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Parallelize.html) but the same option works with `ParallelDo` as well.

You can use

```
Method -> "ItemsPerEvaluation" -> k
```

to ask Mathematica to send `k` tasks to each kernel at a time.

The option

```
Method -> "EvaluatiosPerKernel" -> k
```

tells the system to communicate with each kernel at most `k` times (sending several tasks each time).

There's also `Method -> "CoarsestGrained"` which is the same as `"EvaluatiosPerKernel" -> 1`, i.e. breaks the computation into as many pieces as there are kernels, and `Method -> "FinestGrained"`, which is the same as `"ItemsPerEvaluation" -> 1`.

---

Regarding your questions about processing a list: `ParallelTable[..., {i, list}]`, `ParallelMap[function, list]` or `ParallelCombine`.  Using `Do` is procedural programming. It's somewhat more difficult to parallelize a problem formulated in terms of `Do` than a problem formulated inly in terms of side-effect-less functions.