# How to execute a notebook in background

Tags: notebooks, algorithm, serviceexecute

I am developing an algorithm that take time to return results. I thought if I could run this notebook in background and continue to develop the rest of my work. It is possible to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [(2874)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2874/121)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand your requirements the simplest approach is to set the "background" Notebook to run in a different Kernel.  To do that first configure your kernels:

- Menu **Evaluation** > **Kernel Configuration Options...**
- **Add** a new Kernel, e.g. "Background"

Then in your (background) Notebook use menu **Evaluation** > **Notebook's Kernel** to select it:

[image]

Evaluations in this Notebook will then be run in a separate Kernel leaving `Local` free for others.

- **Caveat:** the number of "master" kernels you can run in parallel is limited by your license; although I have four kernels configured in the image above I can only run two in parallel.