# Can I stop a running NDSolve calculation without losing the data it obtained so far?

Tags: differential-equations, core-language, output

I would like to solve a system of ODEs numerically using `NDSolve` on an interval `{t,t0,tf}`.

For the systems I currently solve, calculations take quite long, and if I pick `tf` too large, it would be nice to have an option to break at some point without losing all data `NDSolve` has obtained so far.

Is there a way, say, to break with the press of the button, but without throwing away the data? So I want to stop the thing, but not abort.

Comment: Maybe you can use the following `WhenEvent` [example](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WhenEvent#541521615) from the documentation?

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/161560/output-of-intermediate-results-from-very-long-ndsolve-computation-into-sequenced/199228#199228

Comment: Related and disappointing in V12 (doesn't work any more): [How to pause a running evaluation (and continue it later)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/135876/26598)

Comment: @CarlWoll I tried to use the stop button. While it worked in the example given in the help file, it doesn't seem to work in the application I would like to use it for. I opened a separate thread to ask for help. If you know what I am doing wrong, help would be much appreciated! : )  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/199890/ndsolve-stopintegration-button-using-whenevent-does-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from the stop `Button[]` example in the docs that Carl pointed out, here are a couple of ways.

The first saves the result periodically using [`` NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[] ``](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStateData.html).

```
ClearAll[sol0];
NDSolve[{y''[x] == -y[x], y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0, 
  WhenEvent[Mod[x, 10] == 0, 
   sol0 = NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[NDSolve`Self]; {}]},
  y, {x, 0, 1000000}]
(*  $Aborted   <-- because I aborted evalutation *)

sol0
```

[image]

Another way to advance the integration bit by bit using [`` NDSolve`Iterate[] ``](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStateData.html).  This has the advantage that after being aborted, one can continue iterating without any further setup.

```
ClearAll[sol0];
{state} = NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{y''[x] == -y[x], y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}, 
  y, {x, 0, 1000000}];

Do[NDSolve`Iterate[state, tt], {tt, 10, 1000000, 10}]
(*  $Aborted   <-- because I aborted evalutation *)

state
(*  NDSolve`StateData[< 0., 12740.>]  <-- shows how far it got (12740.) *)

sol = NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[state]
```

[image]

Here's a way that saves every 1000 steps:

```
ClearAll[sol0];
nsteps = 0;
NDSolve[{y''[x] == -(1 + x/100) y[x], y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0, 
  WhenEvent[Mod[nsteps, 1000] == 0, 
   sol0 = NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[NDSolve`Self]; {}]},
  y, {x, 0, 1000000}, StepMonitor :> ++nsteps]
(*  $Aborted   <-- because I aborted evalutation *)

y["Grid"] /. sol0 // Length
nsteps
(*
  49001
  49602
*)
```

Comment: @MichelE2 Brilliant! Thank you so much for outlining all the options in so much detail! : )